# Duda sobre el orden de evaluación de "and" y "or" en un mismo condicional

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

No tengo claro como conjugar AND y  OR en una misma sentencia condicional.

Por ejemplo:

> Si quiero que en caso de que el campo A sea igual a 'zzz' y el campo B sea igual a 'qqq'

Entiendo que se escribe:

```
if A == 'zzz' and B == 'qqq':
```

Pero me pregunto,

> si quiero que el campo A sea igual a 'zzz' pero tambien quiero que el campo B sea igual a 'qqq' o 'www'

```
A == 'zzz' B == 'qqq'

A == 'zzz' B == 'www'
```

No se si hacer esto es correcto:

```
if mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John' or 'Juan':
```

No tengo claro si estoy usando bien el `or`, para que la condición que se evalué sea "John o Juan", o si bien lo que hace es evaluar si "(numero y John) o Juan"

¿Cómo debería escribirlo?

Comment: Hola Xav. Qué probaste? Si nos muestras tu intento podemos decirte qué tienes mal y como mejorarlo para que aprendas. Un saludo

Comment: Como comenta lois6b si muestras lo que intentas y en que caso falla podemos dar una respuesta fundamentada en ello. Posiblemente sea simplemente  un problema de [orden de evaluación de los operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) que se solventa con `( )`. ¿Cómo se evalua la expresión `a and b or c`?

Comment: Hola chicos, basicamente estoy intentando generar unas condiciones y no tengo claro si hacer esto es correcto. if mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John' or 'Juan':                     No tengo claro si estoy usando bien el or, para que la condicion se cuample sea John o Juan.  O si bien lo que hace es que se cumple el numero y John   o   Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comenté debes tener en cuenta el [orden de evaluación de los operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). El operador `or` tiene preferencia sobre el operador `and`, esto causa que cuando haces:

```
if mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John' or 'Juan':
```

Se evalúa la expresión de izquierda a derecha:

```
if (mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John') or 'Juan':
```

Da igual el valor de `name` o de `mynumber` porque "Juan" siempre se evalúa como `True` ya que no es un string vacío. Cuando haces `name == 'John' or 'Juan'` no evalúas si `name` es "John" o "Juan" sino que evalúas si `name` es "John" o si la cadena "Juan" es `True` (una cadena es evaluada como `True` siempre que no esté vacía). El `or` debe ser:

```
name == 'John' or name == 'Juan'
```

Pero `mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John' or name == 'Juan'` tampoco es lo que deseas, ya que esto lo que hace es evaluar si `mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John'` es `True` o si lo es en cambio `name == 'Juan'`, es decir:

```
(mynumber == '123456' and name == 'John') or name == 'Juan'
```

Para hacer lo que deseas debes envolver ambas igualdades entorno al `or`  con paréntesis:

```
if mynumber == '123456' and (name == 'John' or name == 'Juan'):
```

Comment: Genial!!! Muchas gracias me ha quedado muy claro. Muy bien explicada la respuesta!